# Syntax for evaluating multiple variables for function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do something like

```
f = [x+1 y+2]
values = [1 2]
f(values) = [2 4]
```

(not proper syntax)

`f(values)` only works for taking one variable?

Comment: [Explained in the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f = {@(x) (x+1); @(y) (y+2)}; %//create a cell array of your function handlers
values = [1 2];

%//convert your input values to a cell array
length = numel(values);
v = mat2cell( values, 1, ones(length,1) ).' ; 

%// f(v)
results = cellfun(@(x,y) x(y), f, v);
```